# Is batoto a legal site?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering but is the site batoto a legal manga reading site or not? I noticed on an answer on this question: *[How did the Female Titan cut Eren's titan form?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5197/how-did-the-female-titan-cut-erens-titan-form?answertab=active#tab-top)* has a link, linking to Batoto.

Batoto sounds legal when I was Google Searching it. I have used this site before and enjoy high quality manga and minimal ad's etc however I am probably guessing just like all other manga reading sites on the internet, this ones probably illegal too.

So is Batoto legal?

Comment: Highly doubt it. Again, I don't know why we care about linking to sites that do host scanlations. We've been [told directly by Anna Lear to not care](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8140216#8140216) and our official policy is just [don't ask for, or advertise, links to stuff that is obviously illegal](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/a/406/274).

Comment: @キルア Thanks for the links and thanks for your opinion on the matter. (y) - edit the links out (?).

Comment: IMO, yes, leave the link. It provides context to the answer and does not harm it in any way.

Comment: @キルア Just wanted to say I wasn't trying to be a lawyer :P - Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Batoto distributes unlicensed manga for free, so it's pretty safe to say that it's illegal. They do remove manga once they're officially licensed overseas, which I guess is better than some other sites, but it's still not a licensed provider of any manga I know of.

Moreover, Batoto is one of the many targets of the [recent crackdown](http://www.japantimes.co.jp/news/2014/07/30/national/japan-begins-anti-piracy-campaign-300-internet-sites/) by the Japanese government on piracy sites:

[image]
 <sub>Thanks to Krazer for the image.</sub>

Based on that, it seems pretty clear that for our purposes, this isn't the kind of site we want to be advertising or asking about.

Comment: IMO it's still not something we need to worry about. If we get a DMCA and SE Legal doesn't care to argue fair use (for educational purpose), SE will delete the link and related images.

Comment: @キルア As I've said before, I don't think this is a matter of copyright at all. SE handles copyright procedures, but we have our own image to worry about as well. Not linking to illegal sources in questions or answers is for our own image as a serious anime/manga site; doing anything else would be disrespectful to the creators and the source material.

Comment: Mmmm.... Why should we users enforce Copyright in our sites?

Comment: @Braiam: Have you read the comment before yours? It is just for the image of the site, and if this site is littered with links to illegal manga reading sites, the site may be considered as promoting illegal channel to copyrighted content. Anyway, there is no need of any links to such sites. People can use google to reach them.

Comment: There isn't an official policy we should take. However, if you feel that a link to Botato or whatever site is wrong, feel free to change it to a better link (i.e. Imgur?) which doesn't lead the reader to a site with questionable legality.

Answer (score 1):

We've already had this discussion. We are not lawyers and not meant to be. If the link supplements the answer and adds details, it's not our position to deal with the legality of links.

If Stack Exchange receives a takedown notice, the staff will handle it, or instruct us moderators to handle it.

---

Of course, if the question itself is seeking advice on where to get unlicensed media or about sites with questionable legality, (i.e. the answer will 100% be bad), feel free to close, delete and flag.